# How get value from inside the function in php?

Tags: php, function

I want to get some values from inside of my function, and use them outside for my calculation? Is it possible? I am new to PHP.

Suppose I have code:

```
function snltc($ema)
{ 
    $uemail = $ema;

    $snlc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertree WHERE slot1='$uemail' || slot2='$uemail' || slot3='$uemail' || slot4='$uemail' || slot5='$uemail'");
    $dsnl = mysql_fetch_array($snlc);

    echo $dsnl['supemail'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $dsnl['snlt'];
    $sup1 = $dsnl['supemail'];
    $snltu = $dsnl['snlt'] + 1;
    echo "</br>";
    echo $snltu;
    mysql_query("UPDATE usertree SET snlt='$snltu' WHERE supemail='$sup1'");
    $newsnl = mysql_fetch_array($snlc);
    echo "</br>";
    $snlval = $newsnl['snlt'];
    echo "</br>";
    return $snlval;
}

echo "</br>";
echo snltc('gami@gmail.com');
```

Now, what I want from this code is to use `$snlval` outside of the function and `$sup1` outside of the function. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am beginner please proceed with some detail explanation thanks alot !

Comment: You can use `return $variable`;

Comment: He is already returning... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can return that as array:

```
function snltc($ema){ 
    $uemail = $ema;
    $snlc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertree WHERE slot1='$uemail' || slot2='$uemail' || slot3='$uemail' || slot4='$uemail' || slot5='$uemail'");
    $dsnl = mysql_fetch_array($snlc);
    $sup1 = $dsnl['supemail'];
    $snltu = $dsnl['snlt'] + 1;
    mysql_query("UPDATE usertree SET snlt='$snltu' WHERE supemail='$sup1'");
    $return = array();
    $return['snlval'] = $snltu;
    $return['sup1'] = $sup1;
    return $return;
}
```

then you can use

```
$return = snltc('gami@gmail.com');
echo $return['snlval'];
echo $return['sup1'];
```

Comment: your answer is 100% correct and assuming your answer means there is no other simpler way to fetch variable inside of the function ! thanks alot !

Comment: Glad you understood. It's no other simple way than to return an array containing your variables.

Comment: that is because you are making `"UPDATE usertree"`, I have modified the function. Check now

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
return array($snival, $sup1);
```

Calling the function:

```
$values = snltc($x);
echo $values[0] . $values[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Return both of the values in an array:

```
function snltc($ema)
{
  // ...
  return array($sup1, $snlval);
}

list($sup1, $snlval) = snltc('gami@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

> now what I want from this code is to use $snlval out sideof the
>   function and $sup1 out side of the function how can I achieve this ?

assuming you want to return 2 variables ..
you would put them in an array and return the array so your return statement becomes

```
return array('snlval' => $snlval, 'sup1' => $sup1 );
```

so when you make a call to this function ...

```
$result = snltc('gami@gmail.com');
$snlval = $result['snlval'];
$sup1 = $result['sup1'];
```